# Порекомендуйте книги для написания чат ботов

Tags: python, c++

Всем здравствуйте, можете пожалуйста порекомендовать книги
по теме написания чат-ботов

Comment: У меня бана в гугле нет, у вас, надеюсь, тоже. https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2&rlz=1C1GCEV_ruRU852RU852&oq=%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2&aqs=chrome..69i57.206j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Учебные книги и литература выделены в отдельные топики, поищите в указанном вопросе.